# How to query using TableQuery via IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am exposing my Table via the following method:

```
public static class TableCacheService
{
    public static IEnumerable<Myentity> Read()
    {
        var acc = new CloudStorageAccount(
                     new StorageCredentials("account", "mypass"), false);
        var tableClient = acc.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Myentity");
        return table.ExecuteQuery(new TableQuery<Myentity>());
    }
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
    var nodeHasValue = TableCacheService.Read()
                                        .Where(x => note.ToLower().Contains(x.RowKey.ToLower()))
                                        .Any();
```

But supposedly `x.RowKey` is null!

[image]

It looks like there are 2 members both called `RowKey`. One of them is a `TableEntity`:

[image]

**How do I access the RowKey that is non-null? Am I incorrectly querying the table?**

Comment: Could you provide source code for `Myentity` class?

Comment: @AlexanderI. you were EXACTLY right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have hiding properties `RowKey` and `PartitionKey` inside your `Myentity` class.

I guess your `Myentity` class has something like it:

```
public class Myentity: TableEntity
{
    public new string RowKey { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Pay attention to keyword **new**.

If you have this construction you need to delete this property.

More information about hiding and overriding you can find [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/03/12/whats-the-difference-between-override-and-new/).

Also please review work example with ATS (Azure Table Storage) is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/visual-studio/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-tables).